# question about generating the image in php

Tags: php, captcha

i write the script to generate the image and i write the text on the image. my doubt is if i send the header then only the image is displaying ... without sending header i can't display the images?

I want to display 20 dynamically generated images with different text in one page. so when i create first image and display second will not display because already first image sent the header.

How can i solve this problem.

Thanks on advance.
Madan Sapkota

Comment: Can you provide your code to us?

Answer (score 0):

Either you make one big image and send that or you send a HTML file that contains your 20 images, these will be fetched one by one by the browser and you can send a header everytime :-D

Comment: user will request the gift cards ... every gift card number and price are different ... when they want to see the cards i have to display the image with card number from and price of the card from database. he can see 20/50 cards.

Comment: As far as I get your problem, I stick to my original answer. Do you disagree or is my answer unclear?